# XmlReader.ReadContentAsBase64() fails. Base64 encoded data expected. Found end element

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, base64, xmlreader

In my WCF formatter, I have a `Base64` Content wrapped in an XML-Element `<Binary>...</Binary>`

My Code:

```
bodyReader.ReadFullStartElement("Binary");
byte[] rawBody = bodyReader.ReadContentAsBase64();
```

fails with the Exception:
"System.Xml.XmlException: Base64 encoded data expected. Found end element '' from namespace ''.

To be exact 'bodyReader' is an XmlDictionaryReader.
[ReadContentAsBase64() @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readcontentasbase64(v=vs.110).aspx)
[ReadFullStartElement() @MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404210(v=vs.110).aspx)

Surprisingly, the following workaround works:

```
bodyReader.ReadFullStartElement("Binary");
string b64 = bodyReader.ReadContentAsString();
rawBody = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);
```

though, this Workaround is fine for me,
I'd like to know what am i doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Tried to reproduce on a minimal example, though the following example fails
Note: the Base64 string is the one failing on the `DispatchFormatter`

```
private void TestXmlDictionaryReader()
    {
        string base64 = @"ewpjbGFzc05hbWU6ICJFYmF5IiwKc2hvcE5hbWU6ICJUb21lclNCIgp2YWx1ZTo1Cn0=";
        string s = @"<Binary>ewpjbGFzc05hbWU6ICJFYmF5IiwKc2hvcE5hbWU6ICJUb21lclNCIgp2YWx1ZTo1Cn0=</Binary>";
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(s);
        var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr);
        var xmlDictRdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateDictionaryReader(xr);
        xr.ReadStartElement("Binary");
        byte[] buff = new byte[5000];
        xr.ReadContentAsBase64(buff, 0, 0);
    }
```

2nd thing, `ReadContentAsBase64` signature is different.

**Minimal Reproducable Example**
because it didn't work as a simple method, 
I created a basic WCF project with my (Crippled) Dispatch formatter: [Here on my GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzdxONG_3wXhMU9lejVZUzk4LW8?usp=sharing)

Place Breakpoint @ `NewtonsoftJsonDispatchFormatter.cs` Line 42.

```
42: var bodyReader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
43: bodyReader.ReadStartElement("Binary");
44: byte[] rawBody = bodyReader.ReadContentAsBase64();
```

use any method to send a POST request to your service:

```
POST /Service1.svc/GetData HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1227
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6d7141b8-c6c8-a9c1-f669-06c3c0ccd5e2

{
  className: "Ebay",
  shopName: "TomerSB"
  value:5
}
```

Comment: There is no method `ReadFullStartElement` of [`XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx).  Also, [`ReadContentAsBase64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readcontentasbase64(v=vs.110).aspx) has arguments.  Can you provide an [mcve] for your problem?

Comment: Will do, as soon as I get to my PC.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem.  Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AfbvfE) showing my attempt.  Note that the fiddle doesn't compile because dotnetfiddle does not link in the DLL that contains `XmlDictionaryReader`, but if you run the code in VIsual Studio you will see the test code passes successfully.  Can you provide a full [mcve] including the XML?

Comment: Added Example as WCF Project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i guess the API controller will serialize the string as a XML string literal, which will cause the string to be wrapped in double quotes and cause any other special characters inside the string to escaped with a backslash. so when you try to convert it to byte array it throws exception.